# How to replace just one whitespace with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, replace, removing-whitespace

for example:

```
T h e   t e x t   i s   w h a t   I   w a n t   t o   r e p l a c e
```

I want the result like this:

```
The text is what I want to replace
```

I tried that with shell, sed,

```
 echo 'T h e   t e x t   i s   W h a t   I  w a n t   r e p l a c e'|sed -r "s/(([a-zA-Z])\s){1}/\2/g"|sed 's/\  / /g'
```

it's successfully.
but I don't know how to replace this in **python**. could anybody help me?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to convert a string that has whitespace between each chars:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(.) ', r'\1', 'T h e   t e x t   i s   w h a t   I   w a n t   t o  r e p l a c e')
'The text is what I want to replace'
```

Or, if you want to remove all single whitespace and replace whitespaces to just one:

```
>>> re.sub(r'( ?) +', r'\1', 'A B  C   D')
'AB C D'
```

Comment: @kEvin won't replace a space that is at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @agf Yes, I give an alternative method.

Answer (score 3):

Just for kicks, here is a non-regex solution using string operations:

```
>>> text = 'T h e   t e x t   i s   w h a t   I   w a n t   t o   r e p l a c e'
>>> text.replace(' ' * 3, '\0').replace(' ', '').replace('\0', ' ')
'The text is what I want to replace'
```

(Per the comment, I changed the `_` to `\0` (null character).)

Comment: You might want to use `'\0'` instead of `'_'`.

Comment: IMHO much easier to understand than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, two more ways to do it.  These both assume there is strictly a space after every character that you want.

```
>>> s = "T h e   t e x t   i s   w h a t   I   w a n t   t o   r e p l a c e "
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(.) ')
>>> ''.join(re.findall(pat, s))
'The text is what I want to replace'
```

Even easier, using string slicing:

```
>>> s[::2]
'The text is what I want to replace'
```